# starting a new activity...however only want its asynctask called only once

Tags: android, android-activity, save, android-asynctask, reset

I have two activities

Menu (Activiy)
Contents: Button1 ----> When this is pressed (a new intent is created and shows up Submenu),
   Button2, and
   Button3

Submenu (Activity)
Contents: Contains an async task (called on onCreate()) that downloads information and loads a scrollview.
   Also Contains 3 togglebuttons

When I go to the Menu everything loads up perfectly. Then I press Button1 which also loads up the Submenu and does the Asynctask. However, when I go back to Menu and press Button1 again, nothing is saved on the ScrollView of Submenu of  and everything is reset to original.

What can i do to fix this?

thank you for your time and effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you firstly execute the `AsyncTask`, you should save the data somewhere. Then every next time, you can check if there are any data available. If yes, setup the `ScrollView` and continue, else execute the `AsyncTask`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: what about the states of the togglebutton...that too?

Comment: If you save the state of the togglebutton, yeap this should work too as a check.